# Fetch plist file

Tags: performance, objective-c, ios, hash-map

I have a plist file with many nested dictionaries inside of it, and I wanna fetch them all to my code. Isn't there any more efficient way to do that than nested for-loops?

```
NSArray * keys = [plistDictionary allKeys];
for (NSString * key in keys) {
    // Level 1
    NSLog(@"%@", key );

    BOOL isDictionary = [[plistDictionary objectForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]];
    if (isDictionary) {
        NSArray * keys2 = [[plistDictionary objectForKey:key] allKeys];
        for (NSString * key2 in keys2) {
            // Level 2
            NSLog(@"%@ : %@", key, key2 );

            BOOL isDictionary = [[[plistDictionary objectForKey:key] objectForKey:key2] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]];
            if (isDictionary) {
                // Level 3
                NSArray *keys3 = [[[plistDictionary objectForKey:key] objectForKey:key2] allKeys];
                for (NSString *key3 in keys3) {
                    NSLog(@"%@ : %@ : %@", key, key2, key3 );

                    BOOL isDictionary = [[[[plistDictionary objectForKey:key] objectForKey:key2] objectForKey:key3] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]];
                    if (isDictionary) {
                        // Level 4
                        NSArray *keys4 = [[[[plistDictionary objectForKey:key] objectForKey:key2] objectForKey:key3] allKeys];
                        for (NSString * key4 in keys4) {
                            NSLog(@ "%@ : %@ : %@ : %@",key, key2, key3, key4 );

                            BOOL isDictionary = [[[[[plistDictionary objectForKey:key] objectForKey:key2] objectForKey:key3] objectForKey:key4] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]];
                            if (isDictionary) {
                                // Level 5
                                NSArray * keys5 = [[[[[plistDictionary objectForKey:key] objectForKey:key2] objectForKey:key3] objectForKey:key4] allKeys];
                                for (NSString * key5 in keys5) {
                                    NSLog(@"%@ : %@ : %@ : %@ : %@", key, key2, key3, key4, key5);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing you can do is to store the intermediate objects in variables,
in order to get rid of the repeated and deeply nested `objectForKey:` chains
like

```
NSArray *keys4 = [[[[plistDictionary objectForKey:key] objectForKey:key2] objectForKey:key3] allKeys];
```

Then it would look like this:

```
NSArray * keys = [plistDictionary allKeys];
for (NSString * key in keys) {
    // Level 1
    NSLog(@"%@", key );
    NSDictionary *obj1 = plistDictionary[key];
    if ([obj1 isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSArray * keys2 = [obj1 allKeys];
        for (NSString * key2 in keys2) {
            // Level 2
            NSLog(@"%@ : %@", key, key2 );
            NSDictionary *obj2 = obj1[key2];
            if ([obj2 isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                // Level 3
                NSArray *keys3 = [obj2 allKeys];
                for (NSString *key3 in keys3) {
                    NSLog(@"%@ : %@ : %@", key, key2, key3 );
                    NSDictionary *obj3 = obj2[key3];
                    // ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note also the use of the dictionary subscripting syntax instead of `objectForKey:`.

This can be simplified further by using the `enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:`
method of `NSDictionary`. This method calls the given block once for each
key *and* the corresponding value:

```
[plistDictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key1, NSDictionary *obj1, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"%@", key1);
    if ([obj1 isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        [obj1 enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key2, NSDictionary *obj2, BOOL *stop) {
            NSLog(@"%@ : %@", key1, key2);
            if ([obj2 isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                [obj2 enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key3, NSDictionary *obj3, BOOL *stop) {
                    NSLog(@"%@ : %@ : %@", key1, key2, key3);
                    if ([obj3 isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                        [obj3 enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key4, NSDictionary *obj4, BOOL *stop) {
                            NSLog(@ "%@ : %@ : %@ : %@", key1, key2, key3, key4);
                            if ([obj4 isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                                [obj4 enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key5, NSDictionary *obj5, BOOL *stop) {
                                    NSLog(@"%@ : %@ : %@ : %@ : %@", key1, key2, key3, key4, key5);
                                }];
                            }
                       }];
                    }
                }];
            }
        }];
    }
}];
```

This is still a lot of repeated code, and can be further simplified using
*recursion*:

```
-(void)printPlist:(NSDictionary *)plistDictionary previousKeys:(NSArray *)previousKeys {
    [plistDictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key, NSDictionary *obj, BOOL *stop) {
        NSArray *newKeys = [previousKeys arrayByAddingObject:key];
        NSLog(@"%@", [newKeys componentsJoinedByString:@" : "]);
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            [self printPlist:obj previousKeys:newKeys];
        }
    }];
}

-(void)printPlist:(NSDictionary *)plistDictionary {
    [self printPlist:plistDictionary previousKeys:@[]];
}
```

---

But what if the plist has not only dictionaries but also *arrays* as "nested structures"
(array in dictionary, dictionary in array, array in array, ...)? 
That is not too complicated in the recursive version, we only have to test for 
dictionary or array type. The function now takes an generic `id` parameter
and then enumerates the dict or array and calls itself recursively. We can also 
print the "terminal nodes" or "values", i.e. everything that is not a collection
(strings, numbers, ...):

```
-(void)printPlist:(id)plistObject previousKeys:(NSArray *)previousKeys {
    if ([plistObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        // Enumerate dictionary:
        [(NSDictionary *)plistObject enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
            NSArray *newKeys = [previousKeys arrayByAddingObject:key];
            NSLog(@"%@", [newKeys componentsJoinedByString:@" : "]);
            [self printPlist:obj previousKeys:newKeys];
        }];
    } else if ([plistObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        // Enumerate array:
        [(NSArray *)plistObject enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            NSArray *newKeys = [previousKeys arrayByAddingObject:@(idx)];
            NSLog(@"%@", [newKeys componentsJoinedByString:@" : "]);
            [self printPlist:obj previousKeys:newKeys];
        }];
    } else {
        // Not a collection, print keys and value:
        NSLog(@"%@ = %@", [previousKeys componentsJoinedByString:@" : "], plistObject);
    }
}

-(void)printPlist:(id)plistObject {
    [self printPlist:plistObject previousKeys:@[]];
}
```

That works, but it does not take advantage of the "object-oriented" aspect of 
Objective-C. Here is an alternative implementation:
Each `NSObject` can be dumped as a property list. The default implementation
just prints the keys and the value:

```
@interface NSObject (MRCategory)
-(void)dumpPlistWithLeadingKeys:(NSArray *)keys;
-(void)dumpPlist;
@end

@implementation NSObject (MRCategory) 
-(void)dumpPlistWithLeadingKeys:(NSArray *)leadingKeys {
    NSLog(@"%@ = %@", [leadingKeys componentsJoinedByString:@" : "], self);
}
-(void)dumpPlist {
    [self dumpPlistWithLeadingKeys:@[]];
}
@end
```

The we override the method for `NSDictionary` and `NSArray`:

```
@implementation NSDictionary (MRCategory)
-(void)dumpPlistWithLeadingKeys:(NSArray *)leadingKeys {
    [self enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        NSArray *newKeys = [leadingKeys arrayByAddingObject:key];
        NSLog(@"%@", [newKeys componentsJoinedByString:@" : "]);
        [obj dumpPlistWithLeadingKeys:newKeys];
    }];
}
@end

@implementation NSArray (MRCategory)
-(void)dumpPlistWithLeadingKeys:(NSArray *)leadingKeys {
    [self enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSArray *newKeys = [leadingKeys arrayByAddingObject:@(idx)];
        NSLog(@"%@", [newKeys componentsJoinedByString:@" : "]);
        [obj dumpPlistWithLeadingKeys:newKeys];
    }];
}
@end
```

Now the property list can be dumped with

```
[plist dumpPlist];
```

This is slightly more code, but no if-statements at all, and it can easily be extended
if you need a special "treatment" for some object types.

Comment: You can't imagine how you have made my day by your comment. Thanks with love, Martin :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a relatively simple way to reduce nesting in so-called "arrow code".

It's [guard clauses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_(computer_science)). What you want is to stop when some condition is not fulfilled, instead of continuing if it is fulfilled:

> ```
> if (isDictionary) {
>     NSArray * keys2 = [[plistDictionary objectForKey:key] allKeys];
> ```

Code like this becomes:

```
if (!isDictionary) {
   break;
}
NSArray * keys2 = [[plistDictionary objectForKey:key] allKeys];
```

That aside, the code you use for checking the `isDictionary` is repeated so often, I'd suggest extracting it into a procedure...